# Basic Multivariable/Partial d/dx Question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Question: Let F (x, y) = xy and consider the implicit function F (x, y)=5. Find dx/dy
in two different ways, first by applying the implicit function theorem, then by rewriting x as
an explicit function of y and taking derivatives.

Here is my work:

A) $\frac{\partial \:f}{\partial \:x}=y\:and\:\frac{\partial \:\:f}{\partial \:\:x}=x.\:As\:-\frac{\frac{\partial \:\:f}{\partial \:\:y}}{\frac{\partial \:\:\:f}{\partial \:\:\:x}}\left[at\:F\left(x,y\right)=5\right]=\frac{dx}{dy}\:\left[at\:F\left(x,y\right)=5\right],\:then\:\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{x}{y}$

B) $5=xy\:\rightarrow x=\frac{5}{y}\rightarrow \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{5}{y^2}$

Why am I getting two different answers for A and B? There is clearly an error, but after an hour of redoing the problem I cannot find it.

Comment: Thanks for point that out. I cannot figure out how to generate a vertical bar, so I'm using parentheses to add (at F(x,0)=5). This is from the "Explicit Function Theorem."

Answer (score 2):

as$$x = \frac{5}{y}$$ you can use this on A and get the same value of B
$$\frac{-x}{y}=\frac{5}{y}\frac{-1}{y}=\frac{-1}{y^2}$$

Comment: I appreciate the response. The textbook I'm using (I'm refreshing my calc for an economics class, so I don't have a professor currently I can reach out to) doesn't do this. From the other examples, the textbook seems to imply that A should equal B without any substitutions.

Comment: i know how it is, i´m using a book of mechanical statistics that the author say "The proof is by magic"

Comment: Haha! Well you can commiserate with my situation then. If you're sure this is the only way the problem can be solved, I'll take your word!